# AWS CodeBuild - Unable to find DockerFile during build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Started playing with AWS CodeBuild.

Goal is to have a docker images as a final results with the nodejs, hapi and sample app running inside.

Currently i have an issue with:
"unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /tmp/src049302811/src/Dockerfile: no such file or directory"
Appears on BUILD stage.

Project details:

1. S3 bucket used as a source
2. ZIP file stored in respective S3 bucket contains buildspec.yml, package.json, sample *.js file and DockerFile.
3. aws/codebuild/docker:1.12.1 is used as a build environment.

When i'm building an image using Docker installed on my laptop there is no issues so i can't understand which directory i need to specify to get rid off this error message.

Buildspec and DockerFile attached below.

Thanks for any comments.

```
buildspec.yml

version: 0.1

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1)
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t <CONTAINER_NAME> .
      - docker tag <CONTAINER_NAME>:latest <ID>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<CONTAINER_NAME>:latest
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push <id>.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<image>:latest

DockerFile

FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add nodejs
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY . /src
RUN cd /src; npm install hapi
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["node", "/src/server.js"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the solution was simple.
Issue was related to the Dockerfile name.
It was not accepting DockerFile (with capital F, strange it was working locally) but Dockerfile (with lower-case f) worked perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible you're using a case-insensitive filesystem locally?

Comment: @Unsigned - actually that was the problem. Now everything works fine as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate that Dockerfile exists in the root of the directory? One way of doing this would be to run `ls -altr` as part of the `pre-build` phase in your buildspec (even before ecr login).

Comment: So validation was done adding pwd and ls -altr on pre-build stage.  </br>
For pwd i've got next record within cloud-watch "[Container] 2017/03/22 10:51:48 /tmp/src124893017/src".  </br>
And for DockerFile "[Container] 2017/03/22 10:51:48 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 189 Mar 22 10:51 DockerFile".

It seems that all files are in the right directory.

But again error appears on the same step "[Container] 2017/03/22 10:51:53 unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /tmp/src124893017/src/Dockerfile: no such file or directory".